# UICollectionView displays wrong number of items when current cell is not visible?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an issue regarding the items displayed in my `UICollectionView` that I am not sure how to explain, but I will as detailed as I can in the hopes that someone can help with this.

Currently, I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UICollectionView`. Each `UICollectionCell` contains an image, retrieved from it's `indexPath`.

The following sample code is my implementation of the `UITableViewCell` containing the `UICollectionView`:

```
extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        var cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()

        ....

        if indexPath.section == 4
        {
            if let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell
            {
                if images_ARRAY.isEmpty == false
                {
                    customCell.images_ARRAY = images_ARRAY
                    customCell.awakeFromNib()
                }

                return imagesCell
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet var imagesCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var images_ARRAY = [UIImage]()

    var images = [INSPhotoViewable]()

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        print("awakeFromNib")

        // Through through each image of the record
        for image in images_ARRAY
        {
            images.append(INSPhoto(image: image, thumbnailImage: SomeClass.resized(originalImage: image, withPercentage: 0.3) ) )
        }

        imagesCollectionView.dataSource = self
        imagesCollectionView.delegate = self
    }

    ....

    override func prepareForReuse()
    {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        print("prepareForReuse")

        images.removeAll()
    }
}

extension CustomTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ExampleCollectionViewCell

        print("indexPath.row = \(indexPath.item)")

        cell.populateWithPhoto(images[indexPath.item])

        return cell
    }
}
```

I am using a `UIImagePickerController` in my `MainViewController` to select an image, set it in the `UICollectionViewCell`, and display it in the `UITableViewCell` like so:

```
extension MainViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
{
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {
        if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        {
            // Store and display the image
            if let cell = mainVCTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 4) ) as? CustomTableViewCell
            {
                cell.images_ARRAY.append(selectedImage)

                // Remove any existing images before adding all images again
                cell.images.removeAll()

                cell.awakeFromNib()

                cell.imagesCollectionView.reloadData()

                images_ARRAY = cell.images_ARRAY

                if ( (images_ARRAY.count - 1) % 4) == 0 &&
                        images_ARRAY.count != 1
                {
                    self.mainVCTableView.reloadRows(at: [ IndexPath(row: 0, section: 4) ], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
                }
            }
        }

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController)
    {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Every time the user selects an image, all the images in `images` array is deleted and re-added in from `images_ARRAY` before the `imagesCollectionView` is reloaded. When 4 images are added, the `UITableViewCell` looks like this:

[image]

When the 5th image is added, the `UITableViewCell` dynamically changes its height, hence the `self.mainVCTableView.reloadRows` code, and the row is reloaded whenever the 9th, 13th, 17th, etc.. image is added to expand the height of the `UITableViewCell`:

[image]

The **problem** that I am having is when the 9th image is added, the cell is not visible on screen so when `self.mainVCTableView.reloadRows` is called, which ultimately calls `cellForItemAt` in my `CustomTableViewCell`, the `indexPath.item` is **initially** being reported as **4**, then starts at 0, 1, 2, etc..

The following 2 screenshots is when the **8th** (left) and **9th** (right) image is added to the `UICollectionView`:

[image] [image]

As you can see on the right, the 6th, 7th, and 8th image has disappeared and I have an empty row space where the 9th image should be.

A scroll down the table view shows:

[image]

A print out of the `indexPath.item` when the **9th** image was added shows the following:

```
indexPath.row = 4
indexPath.row = 0
indexPath.row = 1
indexPath.row = 2
indexPath.row = 3
indexPath.row = 4
indexPath.row = 5
indexPath.row = 6
indexPath.row = 7
```

However, once I add the **10th** image, when the `imagesCollectionView` is reloaded, all the images re-appear again:

[image]

A print out after the **10th** image has been added shows:

```
indexPath.row = 0
indexPath.row = 1
indexPath.row = 2
indexPath.row = 3
indexPath.row = 4
indexPath.row = 5
indexPath.row = 6
indexPath.row = 7
indexPath.row = 8
indexPath.row = 9
```

I don't quite understand what is happening? I apologize for the long post but wanted to be specific with my problem and show illustrations so someone can have a better understanding to help me.

Thank you!

Comment: How is the height of the cell determined?

Comment: When adding 9 cells, are you able to scroll the collection view?

Comment: @AhmadF, yes I am able to scroll the collection view as described and seen in the right image

Comment: @vacawama I'm following this sample to determine the cell height: https://medium.com/@adinugroho/fixed-height-uicollectionview-inside-uitableview-79f24657d08f

Comment: Do you have a constraint that connects the bottom of the collectionview to the bottom of the cell?

Comment: @vacawama the `UICollectionView` itself is constrained to all 4 sides of the `UITableViewCell` with constant=0......I wouldn't think the constraints is related to my issue?...but I'm no expert :)

Comment: @Pangu why are you using the collectionView inside the tableView row?
If you want to achieve the above design you could have used simply a UICollectionView with scrollDirection set as vertical

Comment: @AravindAR because my `UITableView` contains multiple data cells that is related to one another, and having a separate `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` makes it harder for me to manipulate the data inside both of them

Comment: @Pangu try reloading collectionView inside cellForRowAtIndexPath inside before returning cell.

Answer (score 1):

Credits to **@Aravind A R** for his suggestion, but the issue has finally been resolved by reloading the `UICollectionView` inside `cellForRowAt` before returning the cell:

```
if images_ARRAY.isEmpty == false
{
    customCell.images_ARRAY = images_ARRAY
    customCell.awakeFromNib()

    customCell.imagesCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```